# Azure AD Role Based Authorization : Allow specific roles for all GET methods and another set of roles for POSTS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, azure

There is a need to authorize the Users based on their Roles, particularly a set of roles that should allow all GET operations and a second set that should allow all POST operations.

**Eg:**

- All Get methods should be accessible to the reader
- Post method access is granted to contributors

I don't want to mark the individual methods with the [Authorize()] as I have ~20 controllers with each supporting all 4 Http Verbs.

I have implemented something like this

```
[RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute(new string[2] { "CJE.Reader", "CJE.Contributor" }, new string[1] { "CJE.Contributor" }, new string[1] { "CJE.Contributor" }, new string[1] { "CJE.Contributor" })]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
```

and

```
public sealed class RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute(string[] getRoleMap, string[] postRoleMap, string[] putRoleMap, string[] deleteRoleMap)
    {
        this.GetRoleMap = getRoleMap;
        this.PostRoleMap = postRoleMap;
        this.PutRoleMap = putRoleMap;
        this.DeleteRoleMap = deleteRoleMap;
    }

    public string[] GetRoleMap { get; }

    public string[] PostRoleMap { get; }

    public string[] PutRoleMap { get; }

    public string[] DeleteRoleMap { get; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!this.IsUserAllowed(context))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    private bool IsUserAllowed(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value);

        switch (context.HttpContext.Request.Method)
        {
            case "GET":
                return this.GetRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            case "POST":
                return this.PostRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            case "PUT":
                return this.PutRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            case "DELETE":
                return this.DeleteRoleMap.Any(r => roles.Contains(r));
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine. However, I feel that this needs to be optimized. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `BaseController`

- There is no need to use the `Attribute` suffix whenever you apply an attribute

```
[RoleBasedAuthorize(new string[2] { ... })]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
```

- If possible please prefer enum over `string` since they are less error-prone

```
[RoleBasedAuthorize(new CJERoles[2] { CJERoles.Reader, CJERoles.Contributor }, ...)]
```

```
public enum CJERoles
{
    [Display(Name = "CJE.Reader")]
    Reader = 0,
    [Display(Name = "CJE.Contributor")]
    Contributor = 1,
}
```

- Please also prefer [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#named-arguments) and line breaks
- I would also suggest to use `xyzRoles` parameter names over `xyzRoleMap`

```
[RoleBasedAuthorize(
    getRoles: new CJERoles[2] { CJERoles.Reader, CJERoles.Contributor },
    postRoles: new CJERoles[1] { CJERoles.Contributor },
    putRoles: new CJERoles[1] { CJERoles.Contributor },
    deleteRoles: new CJERoles[1] { CJERoles.Contributor })]
```

### `RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute`

#### `XYZRoleMap`

- It is good that you have made the properties read-only
- You could also remove the `public` access modifier since they are used only internally

#### `Constructor`

- By accepting enums rather than strings you need to perform some mapping
- I would suggest to map your enums to strings, because I assume not all user roles can be mapped to an enum value

  - In order to ease this mapping I would suggest to introduce the following extension method

```
public static class CJERolesExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this CJERoles enumValue)
        => typeof(CJERoles)
            .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
            .First()
            .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
            .GetName();
}
```

- With this in our hand we can perform the mappings like this

  - First create a local method which can do the mapping
  - Then perform the assignments with the help of [`ValueTuple` and deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct)

```
public RoleBasedAuthorizeAttribute(CJERoles[] getRoles, CJERoles[] postRoles, CJERoles[] putRoles, CJERoles[] deleteRoles)
{
    Func<CJERoles[], string[]> map = roles => roles.Select(role => role.GetDisplayName()).ToArray();

    (GetRoleMap, PostRoleMap, PutRoleMap, DeleteRoleMap) = (map(getRoles), map(postRoles), map(putRoles), map(deleteRoles));
}
```

#### `IsUserAllowed`

- I would suggest to inline this method inside the `OnAuthorization`
- I would also suggest to avoid code duplication use [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) to select the proper `string[]` role map

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity).Claims
        .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
        .Select(c => c.Value);

    var roleMap = context.HttpContext.Request.Method switch
    {
        "GET" => GetRoleMap,
        "POST" => PostRoleMap,
        "PUT" => PutRoleMap,
        "DELETE" => DeleteRoleMap,
        _ => new string[] { }
    };

    if (!roleMap.Any(roles.Contains))
    {
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```